# fabric js canvas.remove() not removing the object

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

so im in the process of trying to implement the undo feature to my app and i ran into an issue, the undo feature works and all however it's either that canvas.remove() doesn't work for some reason or the object:removed event not firing. to make sure that the object does exist i console.log it and sure enough it does exist.. but fabric js doesnt delete the object and neither does it fire the object:removed (obviously) [image: output console.log]

```
canvas.on('object:added',function(){
   h = [];
});
 function undo(){
    if(canvas._objects.length>0){
        console.log(h);
        h.push(canvas._objects.pop());
        var lastItem = h[h.length - 1];
        //Logs the object - check the screenshot
        console.log(lastItem);
        canvas.remove(lastItem);
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
}
 $("#undo").click(function()
{
    undo();
});
 //Not firing even though i removed the object..
  canvas.on('object:removed',function(object)
{
   console.warn(object);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will remove object using `canvas.remove()` then only `'object:removed'` event will fire.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
 left:50,top:50,radius:50,fill:'red'
}))
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
 left:150,top:150,radius:50,fill:'green'
}))
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
 left:250,top:250,radius:50,fill:'blue'
}))
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
 left:250,top:150,width:100,height:100
}));
canvas.requestRenderAll();

function undo(){
 var object = canvas.item(canvas.getObjects().length-1);
 canvas.remove(object);
}

canvas.on('object:removed',function(object){
  console.warn(object);
})
```

```css
canvas{
 border:2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick='undo()'>undo</button>
<canvas id='canvas' width=500 height=400>
```

Comment: im sorry i dont follow you? what am i exactly doing wrong?

Comment: @flex_ as you are doing `canvas._objects.pop()` that last object already removed from object array, and then you are trying to remove from canvas using `canvas.remove`. so that time it wont find the removed object in array, so it wont remove it and wont fire the event. Check the answer, i get the last item from canvas, then removed from canvas.

Comment: @flex_ happy coding ;)

Comment: this is an issue, no matter what i do, the object remains after calling `canvas.remove()` on the active object

Comment: @argon, create a fiddle stating your issue.

Comment: @Durga - The problem is with groups, so you have to ungroup and then romove all objects individually in that selection - only then it works .. learned through trial and error :)

Comment: I'm trying to remove groups, and it just doesn't work. @ user4244405, you are telling me I need to ungroup first and then try to remove individual objects?

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
var objects = canvas.getObjects();
for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
  //console.log(objects[i]);     
  canvas.remove(objects[i]);
}canvas.renderAll();
```